# Joint density multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be independent normal random variables with finite expectation and variance. Then for each $i$ we have $f_{X_i}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}exp(-\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Derive the joint density function of $X_1,\cdots X_n$ and the conditional expectation of $X_n$ given $X_1=x_1,\cdots X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}$ for any $x_1,\cdots x_{n-1}\in\mathbb{R}$.

For the first part I have $f_{X_1,\cdots X_n}=f_{X_1}\times\cdots\times f_{X_n} $ due to independence and this gives an overall joint density of $\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi\sigma^2)^n)}exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(x_1-\mu)^2+\cdots +(x_n-\mu)^2])$.

I have no idea about the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You are assmuing that $X_i$'s are also identically distributed. Is that given to you? If so your answer for the first part is correct. [Otherwise, the means and variances can  depend on $i$].

Since $X_i$'s are independent we have $E(X_n|X_1=x_1,...,X_{n-1}=x_{n-1})=EX_n$.